# shopify sections schema product-handle selector

Tags: shopify, liquid, sections

is there a build in product-handle-selector that renders a dropdown with all products in the sidebar for the sections editor?

I want to do something like this in the

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Gallery Lookbook",
  "class": "gallery-lookbook",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "product",
      "name": "Product",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "product_picker",
          "id": "product-handle",
          "label": "Product"
        }, ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I couldn't believe that it is that easy - that's why I love shopify

```
    {
      "type": "product",
      "id": "product-handle",
      "label": "Product-Handle"
    }
```

Comment: Any idea how to add an image in a block?

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).